# Add multy image to wdContentControlPicture

Tags: c#, office-interop, contentcontrol

I have a template with a `wdContentControlPicture`.

I have 3 byte[] of images. I want to show this in `wdContentControlPicture`.

```
InlineShapes.AddPicture
Shapes.AddPicture
```

But this add one image.

**Edit**

I add a `RichTextContentControl` and add multi shape to it.

```
images.ForEach(i=>
content.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(i.path);)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about "3 byte[] of images"? Is this an array or list of images? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a PictureContentControl can only take one image, by setting the image property, so you need to add 3 controls !

if you use a RichTextContentControl, you probably can add several Shapes to it's range.